# How to use FZF to search directories and open new file in directory

Tags: working-directory, plugin-fzf

Here's what I'd like to do, and I'm open to using any tool (not just fzf):

I want to be able to open a new file quickly (with a horizontal split :sp) in a specific directory that I find using fzf. Say we're working with this structure

```
foo/
  bar/
    file.js
  baz/
```

While I have file.js open in my buffer, I should be able to fuzzy find the foo/baz/ directory and open a new file foo/baz/newfile.js in a split window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this command in my vimrc with fzf.vim, specifically filtering directories in my current git repo.

```
function! s:append_dir_with_fzf(line)
  call fzf#run(fzf#wrap({
    \ 'options': ['--prompt', a:line.'> '],
    \ 'source': 'git ls-files $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq',
    \ 'sink': {line -> feedkeys("\<esc>:".a:line.line, 'n')}}))
  return ''
endfunction

cnoremap <expr> <c-x><c-d> <sid>append_dir_with_fzf(getcmdline())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fzf.vim, it has the wrapper for Files, (and GFiles, which respect the gitignore while searching)

Under current directory, run `:Files`, fzf will open a list of files to search. Remember, this only search **file names**, not file's contents.

Hit `c-x` for split, or `c-v` for vsplit.

If you want to preview the content inside the file, set this in .vimrc:

```
" Likewise, Files command with preview window
command! -bang -nargs=? -complete=dir Files
  \ call fzf#vim#files(<q-args>, fzf#vim#with_preview(), <bang>0)
```

It will show the preview content next to the search list.

I set the shortcut to `sf` (in my mind, it is `search files`, so I can quickly open it)

```
nmap <silent> sf :FzfFiles<cr>
```

If you want to search the content inside the files, use :Ag.

Read the [fzf.vim documentation](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) for more information.